# Why on all real estate websites you need to click to show the phone number?

Tags: call-to-action, cta, phone-numbers, product-details

I've noticed that on all real estate websites, any country, in the details page of a property, there's always a button/field that says "*show phone number*"... and all it takes to see the phone number is **just a click!** I haven't seen any website where it takes more than a click to show the phone number... no login/signup required, no restrictions such as "first match" (a bit like on Airbnb)...

Seems kind of pointless of hiding the phone number in the first place. Is it just an easy gimmick to track interest? Is it a "manufactured" CTA?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believed it's for analytics purposes. Can't talk for every real estates website though but the one I had as customers gave me that reason. :)

Comment: Welcome to the UXSE community. Please add more information/references to support your answer. In case it is meant to be a commentary on the question, kindly post it as a comment once you have the minimum required reputation

Comment: Hello @ShreyasTripathy. Can you please explain to me why I didn't answer the question ? The question is "Why on all real estate websites you need to click to show the phone number?" and I answered "I believed it's for analytics purposes.". How can I be more specific? Adding case studies, personal experiences ?